# Livewire child component is not pushing js

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Im trying to show (render) a child component

```
@if ($tipo_sesion == App\Models\Evento::DICTAMINACION || $tipo_sesion == App\Models\Evento::AMBOS)
            <livewire:components.procedimientos proceso="edit" />
        @endif
```

this component is showed or not depending on conditions and when its true the childs js is not working because scripts are not being pushed to the @stack('js') directive. I ve tried to $refresh the child component but doesnt work.

Heres my child component view with js

```
<div>
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <h4 class="text-lead">Procedimientos de contratación</h4>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
                                wire:click="$dispatch('open-modal',['add_procedimiento'])">
                                Agregar procedimiento
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                   
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
@push('js')
        <script type="module">
            const monto_mdp_procedimiento = document.getElementById('monto_mdp_procedimiento');
            const monto_disponibilidad = document.getElementById('monto_disponibilidad');
            const update_monto_disponibilidad = document.getElementById('monto_disponibilidad_update');
            const update_monto_mdp_procedimiento = document.getElementById('update_monto_mdp_procedimiento');


            console.log(monto_mdp_procedimiento, monto_disponibilidad, update_monto_disponibilidad,
                update_monto_mdp_procedimiento);
            // mask(monto_mdp_procedimiento, maskNumberOptions)
            // mask(monto_disponibilidad, maskNumberOptions)

            // mask(update_monto_disponibilidad, maskNumberOptions)
            // mask(update_monto_mdp_procedimiento, maskNumberOptions)
        </script>
    @endpush
</div>
```

Is there a way to rescan() the dom for newly added components? like in V2?